# Is it necessary to explicitly indicate the WORKDIR for each command in my Dockerfile?

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, workdir

I have the following file structure:

[image]

**Dockerfile**:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /home/pos

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY /src /src
    
CMD ["python", "src/manage.py", "runserver"]
```

I expect that the content of the src/ folder will be copied to the same path in the container (home/pos/src/) but only the requirements.txt are copied to that path, the content of the /src folder is being copied to the "root" (/), so I need to change the command to:

```
COPY /src /home/pos/src
```

It is necessary to set the WORKDIR for each command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an absolute path on the right-hand side of `COPY` then it uses an absolute path in the container.  If you use a relative path then it is relative to the current `WORKDIR`.  In your Dockerfile you have an absolute path `/src` so that's the destination, but if you change it to a relative path

```sh
COPY ./src/ ./src/
```

it will be under the current `WORKDIR`.

I'd suggest avoiding as many paths and filenames as possible on the right-hand side of `COPY`; for example you can also `COPY requirements.txt ./`.

(The rules for the left-hand side of `COPY` are a little different: all leading `..` path components are stripped, then regardless of whether it's an absolute or relative path it's interpreted as a path underneath the build-context directory.  So even if the source looks like an absolute path it's often interpreted as a path relative to the Dockerfile.  Again, using a relative path on the left-hand side of `COPY` is probably clearer.)